# How to add jquery third party plugin in rails 6 webpacker

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpacker, ruby-on-rails-6

I know its simple but with update of rails 6. there is new syntax in rails 6 for manage javascript assets which is maintained by webpacker.

```
//application.js
require("@rails/ujs") //.start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require('jquery').start()
require('jquery_ujs').start()
require('bootstrap-daterangepicker').start()
require("custom/custom").start()
require("bootstrap").start()
require("channels")
```

i am able to add `custom/custom` but bootstrap and jquery is not working
i have install jquery and bootstrap via npm

Answer (score 27, accepted):

run below command to add jQuery.

```
$ yarn add jquery
```

Add below code in `config/webpack/environment.js`

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery'
  })
)
```

Require jquery in application.js file.

```
require('jquery')
```

No more need to add jquery-rails gem!

Comment: Why you need `$` and `jQuery`?

Comment: @truongnm we have to define these variables globally so webpack willbe able to compile the packs.

Comment: /config/webpack/environment.js

Comment: After moving jQuery from the pipeline to Webpack I get a console error "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery".

Comment: Now I'm getting the duplicate request. Any help?

Answer (score 17):

to resolve jquery third party plugin issue add jquery via yarn

```
yarn add jquery
```

for adding jquery support in rails 6 application first we need to add below configuration

```
# app/config/webpack/environment.js
const {environment} = require('@rails/webpacker');

const webpack = require('webpack');
environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery' # or if its not work specify path `'jquery/src/jquery'` which node_modules path for jquery
}));

module.exports = environment;
```

for import any jquery related plugin in `app/javascripts/packs/application.js`

use below instructions

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker'
```

## updated with `expose-loader` for jQuery

```
yarn add expose-loader
```

Then add this to config/webpack/environment.js

```
   environment.loaders.append('jquery', {
      test: require.resolve('jquery'),
      use: [{
        loader: 'expose-loader',
        options: '$',
      }, {
        loader: 'expose-loader',
        options: 'jQuery',
      }],
    });
    module.exports = environment;
```

Comment: What if we add another library other than jquery? like this lib: https://github.com/apvarun/toastify-js

Comment: what issue are you facing?

Comment: I don't know how to write that lib into environment.js and when I import in application.js I got "Root element not define" and "Toastify not defined"

Comment: did you import toastify in application.js pack and if yes how did you import it

Comment: I did `yarn` and go to nodes_module folder and make sure that library folder name is `toastify-js`

Comment: Why you need `$` and `jQuery`?

Comment: This doesn't work unless I do `jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery',` why is that?

Comment: @ArianFaurtosh I think we need to specify a source file path in this section.

Comment: I found that for adding jquery 3rd party plugins (my example is 'jquery-mask-plugin'), add jquery as above, add expose-loader as above, but then instead of `import 'jquery-mask-plugin'` which didn't work, adding `require("jquery-mask-plugin")` to `application.js` worked.

Comment: got `TypeError: Cannot read property 'ProvidePlugin' of undefined ` for the first solution

Comment: second solution with the `expose-loader` worked for me in `Rails 6.0.2.2` and yarn `1.16.0`.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently expose-loader 1.0.0 has a different format:

```
environment.loaders.append('jquery', {
  test: require.resolve('jquery'),
  rules: [
    {
      loader: 'expose-loader',
      options: {
        exposes: ['$', 'jQuery'],
      },
    },
  ],
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you have yarn installed and updated to the latest version, then create your rails application.

First Run the following command to install Bootstrap, Jquery and Popper.js

```
yarn add bootstrap@4.5 jquery popper.js
```

On the above ofcourse you can change to the latest version of Bootstrap.

If you open package.json file, you will notice Bootstrap 4.5, Jquery latest version and Popper.js latest versions have been added for you.

Next go to config/webpack/environment.js and amend the file.

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
    
const webpack = require("webpack")

environment.plugins.append("Provide", new webpack.ProvidePlugin({

$: 'jquery',

jQuery: 'jquery',

Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']

}))

module.exports = environment
```

Next go to app/assets/stylesheets/application.css and amend the file make sure to require bootstrap.

```
*= require bootstrap

*= require_tree .

*= require_self
```

Finally go to application.js file and amend the file by adding `import 'bootstrap';` in order for bootstrap javascript to work.

```
import 'bootstrap';
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
```

Save all changes, restart rails server.

That should work.

Answer (score 1):

In webpacker v. 6 there is no `config/webpack/environment.js` and other files structure

Firstly you need add JQuery to your project using `yarn`:

```
yarn add jquery
```

After that you can integrate JQuery using one of ways:

1. Directly update base config:

```
// config/webpack/base.js

const { webpackConfig } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const webpack = require('webpack')

webpackConfig.
  plugins.
  push(
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery'
    })
  )

module.exports = webpackConfig
```

2. Use custom config and merge it to base config:

```js
// config/webpack/base.js

const { webpackConfig, merge } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const customConfig = require('./custom')

module.exports = merge(webpackConfig, customConfig)
```

```js
// config/webpack/custom.js

const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery'
    })
  ]
}
```

On my opinion second way is more flexible