# How to use jQuery hover() Method for Ruby on Rails 6.0.2.2 version

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-hover

I would like to learn ruby on rails and ı'm traying some project. I want to see an explanation when I hover over the photo with the mouse. I know,  how can ı use jquery hover but only rails **5.2 version** but ı have rails **6.0.2.2 version** .Now how can ı use hover for **rails 6.0.2.2 version** . You can see error message and my photo on the screenshot. And finally thank you for your help

**Error ScreenShot** = [[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjTUF.png]

related code line for jquery Hover
**Shot.js**

```
shotHover() {
                $('.shot').hover(function() {
                    $(this).children('.shot-data').toggleClass('visible');
                });
            }

Shots.shotHover();
```

**application.js**

```
// This file is automatically compiled by Webpack, along with any other files
// present in this directory. You're encouraged to place your actual application logic in
// a relevant structure within app/javascript and only use these pack files to reference
// that code so it'll be compiled.

require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("shots")



// Uncomment to copy all static images under ../images to the output folder and reference
// them with the image_pack_tag helper in views (e.g <%= image_pack_tag 'rails.png' %>)
// or the `imagePath` JavaScript helper below.
//
// const images = require.context('../images', true)
// const imagePath = (name) => images(name, true)
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to shot, class: "shot" do %>
          <%= image_tag(shot.user_shot_url) %>
          <div class="shot-data">
            <h3 class="shot-title"><%= shot.title %></h3>
            <div class="shot-description"><%= truncate(shot.description, length: 60) %></div>
            <div class="shot-time">
              <%= time_ago_in_words(shot.created_at) %>
            </div>
          </div>
        <% end %>
```

I have jquery in Gemfile like this.
**Gemfile**

```
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.3', '>=4.3.1'
```

Comment: Rails 6 uses webpacker for javascript assets. See this question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54905026/how-to-add-jquery-third-party-plugin-in-rails-6-webpacker

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. Rails 6 have some new innovation.

In our Rails application run below command to add jQuery.

```
$ yarn add jquery
```

It will save the dependency of jquery to our application.

Now to verify jquery is installed or not, check below files

```
package.json => "jquery": "^3.3.1",
yarn.lock => jquery@^3.3.1:
```

Add below code in environment.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery'
  })
)
```

Now, our file looks like,

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery'
  })
)

module.exports = environment
```

Require jquery in application.js file.
it's looks like,

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("jquery")
```

That's all .You can use jquery on your project