# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined in Rails 6 jquery webpacker

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker

I am using `Rails 6.0.3.2`, `ruby 2.7.1`, `yarn 1.22.0`.

I am trying to do normal `UJS` stuff, and this is the error I am getting:

```
VM125:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
    at processResponse (rails-ujs.js:283)
    at rails-ujs.js:196
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (rails-ujs.js:264)
```

This is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/actiontext": "^6.0.2-2",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "4.2.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "data-confirm-modal": "^1.6.2",
    "expose-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "flickity": "^2.2.1",
    "jquery": "3.4.1",
    "local-time": "^2.1.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "stimulus": "^1.1.1",
    "trix": "^1.0.0",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
  }
}
```

This is my `environment.js`:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery',
  Rails: '@rails/ujs'
}))

// environment.loaders.append('jquery', {
//     test: require.resolve('jquery'),
//     use: [{
//         loader: 'expose-loader',
//         options: '$',
//     }, {
//         loader: 'expose-loader',
//         options: 'jQuery',
//     }],
// });

module.exports = environment
```

As you can see from the commented out code above, I also tried using `expose-loader` per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54906972/91970) but that gave me other errors.

In my `application.js`, I have the following:

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("local-time").start()
require("jquery")

import '../src/jquery.min'
.
.
.
import "controllers"

require("trix")
require("@rails/actiontext")
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: jQuery has been imported twice. Remove 
import '../src/jquery.min' and require jQuery before ujs.

Comment: @RaviTejaGadi I just tried that and it didn't fix the issue. It does clean up my code, so I appreciate the tips, but it didn't fix the error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add below code in :
`app/javascript/packs/application.js`

```
window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;
```

So jQuery keywords could be picked up.

Comment: So this is the weirdest thing. I tried this before, but perhaps I had put it too high in the file, cuz I just tried it again and it works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: This is such a random horrible issue, but this fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of issues migrating from webpacker 5 to shakapacker. Adding

`import "expose-loader?exposes=$,jQuery!jquery"`

To the top of `application.js` fixed the jQuery issues