# jQuery not being loaded in Webpack

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, webpack

I am in the process of moving my entire `application.js` application into smaller page bundles using SplitChunks. In my `users/show.html.erb` page I am using the following tag to import the specific chunk.

`<%= javascript_packs_with_chunks_tag 'users/show' %>`

From the looks of my source code when I inspect it there are several bundles included such as the `application.js` file that includes jquery like this...

```
import "bootstrap"
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("jquery")
```

I am just testing the page to see if jquery is being loaded. My `users/show.js` code looks like this:

```
import "chartkick"
import "chart.js"

window.onload = function() {
  if (window.jQuery) {  
      // jQuery is loaded  
      alert("Yeah!");
  } else {
      // jQuery is not loaded
      alert("Doesn't Work");
  }
}
```

When I load the page I do see a `Doesn't Work` alert pop up indicating that jQuery has not been loaded. I'm newer to webpack so perhaps I have some misconfiguration somewhere, but if jquery is being loaded at the application.js level, why would my other pack not be able to listen to use jquery? Is this a problem with the dependency graphs?

My environment is as follows:

```
environment.js
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker');
const webpack = require('webpack');

environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
 $: 'jquery',
 jQuery: 'jquery',
 Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
}));
const config = environment.toWebpackConfig();
config.resolve.alias = {
 jquery: 'jquery/src/jquery'
};

environment.splitChunks()
module.exports = environment;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you add `jQuery` alias to your global (window) object. So you have to add it as below:

```js
global.jQuery = jQuery; // This is a alias you defined in `ProvidePlugin`;
// window.jQuery = jQuery // also works

// Or you can add directly via your required object
const jquery = require('jquery');
global.jQuery = jquery;
```

Comment: Where does `global.jQuery` go? Environment.js or Application.js?

Comment: It's best to place at your `Application.js` where you import `jquery`

Answer (score 0):

I invariably get this issue and here is the two lines which makes it working for me

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/q/54905026/398863
window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;
```