# Cant get packages to work with yarn + webpacker + Ruby on Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yarnpkg, webpacker, bootstrap-select, metismenu

I am trying to make Metismenu and Bootstrap-select work on Rails 6.

I installed them both through yarn. They both show up in package.json

Placed in application.js

```
require('bootstrap');
require('bootstrap-select');
require('metismenu');
```

Enable them with

```
$('#metismenu').metisMenu();
$('[data-toggle="multiselect-dropdown"]').selectpicker();
```

However both give a error

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).metisMenu is not a function
```

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).selectpicker is not a function
```

After some digging I can't seem to find the cause of this. Anyone can help me?

Comment: `jquery` $ maybe nil, you need to [add jquery third party plugin in rails 6 webpacker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54905026/how-to-add-jquery-third-party-plugin-in-rails-6-webpacker)

Comment: Thank you, but Jquery is successfully loaded and working without problems.

Comment: make sure you import $ before call those functions: `import $ from "jquery";`

Comment: This seems to have solved the problem! Thank you!